# Batch export all open windows in Gimp

Tags: python, gimp, script-fu, python-fu, gimpfu

I just manually edited 200+ .PDF files in gimp and I would like to batch export all of them at once (in .PDF) instead of exporting one by one.

I have the `plugin-registry` installed, but I'm not sure if I can take advantage of it in this case.

I think what I need is a script / console command, but I know nothing about Python.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I need to open a bunch of files, then export all of them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem. My solution was:

1. copy images to subdirectory
2. open all copied images and edit them how you want.
3. use the saveALL.scm script provided below (i can't remember where i found it). this script will overwrite opened files, but will save your edits on all opened images.
4. if you're like me and you want to the edited output file to be a different format, follow up with ImageMagic and convert all files in the subdirectory using the mogrify function.

   ```
   ; This program is free software
   ; you can redistribute it and/or modify 
   ; it under the terms of the GNU General Public 
   ; License as published by 
   ; the Free Software Foundation
   ; either version 2 of the License, or 
   ; (at your option) any later version. 
   ; 
   ; This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, 
   ; but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of 
   ; MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the 
   ; GNU General Public License for more details. 

   (define (script-fu-save-all-images) 
     (let* ((i (car (gimp-image-list))) 
            (image)) 
       (while (> i 0) 
         (set! image (vector-ref (cadr (gimp-image-list)) (- i 1))) 
         (gimp-file-save RUN-NONINTERACTIVE 
                         image 
                         (car (gimp-image-get-active-layer image)) 
                         (car (gimp-image-get-filename image)) 
                         (car (gimp-image-get-filename image))) 
         (gimp-image-clean-all image) 
         (set! i (- i 1))))) 

   (script-fu-register "script-fu-save-all-images" 
    "<Image>/File/Save ALL" 
    "Save all opened images" 
    "Saul Goode" 
    "Saul Goode" 
    "11/21/2006" 
    "" 
    )
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked for me on MacOS 10.10.5 with GIMP 2.8.22.